# How to get a distinct values in two fields by referencing only on the single field from a database in LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

How to get the distinct value from a database by referencing to a **single column only**.

For example in the given data below the result would be... Please see example below.

Given Data

```
Prospect    Values
1            null
1            null
2            2.1
2            2.2
2            2.3
3            3.1
3            3.2
4            4.1
4            4.2
```

Result

```
Prospect    Values
1            null
2            2.1
3            3.1
4            4.1
```

The distinct value is referencing to the **prospect column**. Is this possible in LINQ?

Thanks

RJ

Comment: It is not clear how the output values are related to the input ones. Please clarify.

Comment: SOrry, its now updated.  The output will always be the 1st occurrence of the prospect row.

Comment: Your data is DataTable or list of object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (untested)

```
var q  = from row in rowList
         group row by row.Prospect into prospects
         select new { Prospect = prospects.Key, 
                      Value = prospects.First().Values };
```

Assuming `rowList` is some sort of `IEnumerable<Row>`, and Row type has fields `Prospect` and `Values`, among others.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var results =
    values
        .ToLookup(x => x.Prospect, x => x.Value)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Prospect = x.Key,
            Value = x.First()
        });
```

Starting with this:

```
var values = new []
{
    new { Prospect = 1, Value = (double?)null },
    new { Prospect = 1, Value = (double?)null },
    new { Prospect = 2, Value = (double?)2.1 },
    new { Prospect = 2, Value = (double?)2.2 },
    new { Prospect = 2, Value = (double?)2.3 },
    new { Prospect = 3, Value = (double?)3.1 },
    new { Prospect = 3, Value = (double?)3.2 },
    new { Prospect = 4, Value = (double?)4.1 },
    new { Prospect = 4, Value = (double?)4.2 },
};
```

I get these results:

[image: results]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a custom `IComparer` and provide it to the `Distinct` method.

Ive made a generic version that takes a lambda for the implementation of compares.  You also override `GetHashValue` which is checked first.  In this case you could just return the comparison of prospect.